# How to use emulators in cloud computing for development

Tags: java, cloud, cloud-platform

I am a new one in cloud computing and i cant understand the emulators and how to use emulators for cloud computing development using java. Please give me some knowledge about all of these for better understand.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud computing emulators/simulators are used to perform various operations and management of cloud computing resources in a simulated/virtual environment without the actual need of real cloud. These emulators are mainly used for research and academic purpose. We use simulators because experimenting in real cloud is costly as real cloud is chargeable and for research purpose it doesn't provide much libraries and methods to implement our own techniques. So generally people first use simulators/emulators to experiment and compare it's results and then use real cloud. Using emulators a huge amount of cost and time are saved. There are various cloud computing emulators available like

**CloudSim**- It is the most widely used simulator for cloud. It is developed in java. It provides built-in methods and libraries to simulate various computing tasks like creating datacenters, Virtual machines inside it, creating network, running cloudlet(task) inside a VM, load balancing, power consumption and management etc. It is an open source simulator so user can modify the source and implement various methods according to his/her need.

**WorkflowSim**- It is an extension to CloudSim  and is mainly sued for scheduling workflows,tasks,jobs etc and creating scheduling methods/policies for cloud.

**SmartFed**- To implement cloud federation in simulated environment. It is also   in java.

**GreedCloud**- This is used for performing experiments of energy efficient cloud computing. It focuses on energy consumption in datacenters.

**CloudAnalyst-** It is used for modeling and analysing large scale internet applications. It provides a framework for deploying real-time data centres and monitoring load balancing, cloud cluster monitoring and data centre data flow .

To read more about open source cloud simulators read the below link
[Read here more about open source simulators](http://opensourceforu.com/2016/11/best-open-source-cloud-computing-simulators/)